# How would you translate all values in pandas column to values from MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas Data-Frame and I also have MySQL database.

```
              Fund
0   ABCA Reversion
1       Edgestream
2             Sink
```

I first attempted to do one MySql query with WHERE IN statemement.

```
SELECT idManagerEntity  
FROM mydb.`manager entity` 
WHERE `name` in ('ABCA Reversion','Edgestream','Sink')
ORDER BY FIELD (`name`,'ABCA Reversion','Edgestream','Sink')
```

This works fine for the example given, however some of my examples have unordered duplications such as.

```
              Fund
0             Sink
1       Edgestream
2             Sink
3             Voyo
```

The mentioned query would only return three values without the taking into account the second Sink value.

What would be the best approach? I suppose I could go making individual queries posibly by the apply function.

Answer (score 1):

Use [FIELD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_field) correctly. It starts with the value.

```
ORDER BY FIELD (name, 'ABCA Reversion','Edgestream','Sink')
```

Comment: You're right I made a mistake in the code. However the question still remains the order by discounts the duplicate.